# Turn off retina internal display while connected to external monitor in Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, display

How do you turn off the MacBook retina internal display with the lid open while using an external monitor on Mac OS X 10.12.6 Sierra?
All the previous method doesn't work!
1.Turning down the brightness is not the same as turning off the display as the GPU still sends a signal to the internal display and the external monitor.
2.These were the terminal commands to achieve this on Mavericks:
Enable
sudo nvram boot-args="iog=0x0"
Disable
sudo nvram -d boot-args
3.sudo nvram boot-args=niog=1
4.sudo pmset -a lidwake 0.

So, how can i do it without use the third party app?
Thank you

Comment: Plug in an AC adapter and close the lid?

Answer (score 0):

> From  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834 Published Date: Jun 6,
>   2017
>
> ...
>
> You can use an external display or projector with a Mac notebook while
>   its built-in display is closed. This is known as closed-clamshell or
>   closed-display mode.
>
> Requirements for closed-display mode
>
> To use closed-display mode with your Mac notebook, you need:
>   - An AC power adapter
>   - An external keyboard and mouse or trackpad, either USB or wireless
>   - A USB-C to USB adapter if you're using a USB mouse or keyboard with MacBook (2015 and later) or MacBook Pro (2016 and later)
>   - An external display or projector
>
> Enable closed-display mode
>
> Use these steps to enable closed-display mode. If the external display
>   isn't recognized when it's connected and your Mac is powered on, try
>   connecting the display while your computer is asleep or off. Then wake
>   or turn on the computer after you connect the display.
>
> If you're using a USB keyboard and mouse
>
> 1. Make sure that your Mac notebook is plugged in to an outlet using the AC power adapter.
> 2. Connect a USB keyboard and mouse to your Mac.
> 3. With your Mac turned on and the display open, connect the Mac to the appropriate port on the external display or projector and turn the
>      display or projector on. Use an appropriate Apple video adapter if
>      necessary.
> 4. After your Mac notebook's Desktop appears on the external display, close the computer's lid.
> 5. When you close the lid:
>
>    - In OS X Lion 10.7 and later, the external display changes to a blue screen, then shows your Desktop.
>    - In OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard and earlier, you can wake your Mac by clicking the mouse button or pressing a key on the external keyboard.
>        You can now use your Mac notebook as you normally would with a USB
>        keyboard and mouse.
>
> If you're using a wireless keyboard and mouse
>
> 1. Make sure that your Mac notebook is plugged in to an outlet using the AC power adapter.
> 2. Verify that Bluetooth is turned on in the Bluetooth pane of System Preferences or the Bluetooth menu icon Bluetooth icon.
> 3. Pair your Bluetooth keyboard or mouse with your Mac.
> 4. In the Bluetooth pane of System Preferences, click Advanced and make sure the checkbox next to Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this
>      computer is selected.
> 5. With your Mac turned on and the display open, connect the Mac to the appropriate port on the external display or projector and turn the
>      display or projector on. Use an appropriate Apple video adapter if
>      necessary.
> 6. After your Mac notebook's Desktop appears on the external display, close the computer's lid.
> 7. When you close the lid:
>
>    - In OS X Lion 10.7 and later, the external display changes to a blue screen, then shows your desktop.
>    - In OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and earlier, you can wake your Mac by clicking the mouse button or pressing a key on the external keyboard.
>
> You can now use your Mac notebook as you normally would with a
>   wireless keyboard and mouse.
>
> Disconnect your Mac notebook from the display after use
>
> It's best to put your Mac to sleep by choosing Apple menu > Sleep
>   before disconnecting your display.
>
> Some DVI and Mini DisplayPort displays — including Apple's
>   aluminum-framed DVI displays and the 24-inch and 27-inch LED Cinema
>   Displays — can be unplugged without putting the computer to sleep. If
>   you aren't sure whether your display supports this feature, put your
>   computer to sleep before unplugging the display.
>
> Opening the internal display while in closed-display mode
>
> Opening the display on your Mac notebook while it's in closed-display
>   mode will have different results based on the operating system you're
>   using.
>
> OS X Lion 10.7 and later     If you open the lid of your supported Mac
>   notebook computer running OS X Lion 10.7 and later while in
>   closed-display mode, the display flickers to a blue screen after a few
>   moments, and then both displays become active. Close the lid to return
>   to closed-display mode.
>
> OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and earlier     If you open the lid of your
>   supported Mac notebook computer running OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and
>   earlier while in closed-display mode, it might appear to have no
>   video. This is expected behavior. When your computer is in
>   closed-display mode, the built-in display is disabled and all video
>   memory is allocated to the external display.    To reactivate your
>   built-in display, put the computer to sleep and then wake it, or use
>   the Detect Displays button in the Displays pane of System Preferences.
>   You can also press Command-F1 on keyboards that don't have a Numlock
>   key.

Comment: I think this is a quote from somewhere? If so, you should attribute it with a link, and then pull out and quote just the relevant part.

Comment: This wall of text, while hard to read, doesn't answer the OP's question because the question specifically states "with the lid open"

Comment: Ok I will do it actually I can't format my answer right now because I am busy right now.